# How to use webpack devServer proxy in create react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, create-react-app

I'm creating a new app by using create-react-app and I want to add some proxies for my code. Previously I have used webpacks devServer

```js
module.exports = {
  ...
  devServer: {
    proxy: {
      '/api/context*': {
        target: 'http://some.endpoint.com',
        headers: myCustomerHeaders,
        pathRewrite: (path, res) => changeThePath
      }
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

I have tried using the same approach in both webpack.config.dev.js and the webpackDevServer.config.js as well as putting it start.js as proxyConfig that is being passed to the webpackDevServer.config.js.

I see writings of src/setupProxy.js but is it applicable without expressJs running somewhere? Anyway I tried it without any result. The paths I'm proxying to are test environment api's that I wish to use.

I have used create-react-app as a new skeleton for an old application to upgrade it, my old project works with the proxy settings.

Now that I'm using create-react-app, I expected the same way be plausible, but it seems I am wrong. Any takers of what I am doing wrong?

Comment: can you please tell , if we implement ```http proxy  middleware``` in to react app , do we required `proxy keyword like  ``proxy :"somevalue" ``` in ``` package.json``` . Does it work without this keyword in package.json file ?  @Thomas Johansen

Comment: as I recall the answer by @Valerii is all you need. If you don't use CRA, which is much simpler to be honest, you can use proxy option in devServer in webpack config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use "http-proxy-middleware"

https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware

```
var express = require('express')
var proxy = require('http-proxy-middleware')

var app = express()

app.use('/api', proxy({ target: 'http://www.example.org', changeOrigin: true }))
app.listen(3000)
```

Comment: I misunderstood the use of the library. Thanks :)